# A differential operator associated with a vector field on the torus

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-operators, index-theory

Assume that $X$ is  a  non vanishing  vector  field  on the  torus $\mathbb{T}^2$.

We  define two  linear  operators $T,S$ on the  space  of  smooth  functions on  $\mathbb{T}^2$ as  follows:

$T(f)=X.f$
$S(f)= *d(\alpha_{f})$   where $*$ is  the  Hodge operator and    $\alpha_{f}$  is  the   $1\; \_$ form  on the  torus with  $\alpha_{f}(h)=fX.h$ the  later  is  based on  a  Riemannian metric  on the  torus.

> Is  $D=T^2+S^2$ an  elliptic  operator?If  yes  is its  index depend on the  vector  field  $X$  and  a Riemannain metric on the  torus?If the  index depends  on $X$, are  there  some  dynamical interpretation  for the  index of  this  operator?

Comment: so $h$ is a vector field right ?

Comment: @ThomasRichard  Yes  it is a tangent  vector.

Comment: Computations show that $Df=|X|_g^2\Delta_g f+\dots$ where the terms in the dots depend on $f$ and $df$. So ellipticity is ok since your vector field is non vanishing, as for the index I have no idea.

Comment: @ThomasRichard  Thank you for  your  comment.

Comment: Also, when $g$ is a flat metric and $X=\partial_x$, $D$ is just the usual laplacian. One can always deform (conformally for instance) a Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{T}^2$ to a flat one. I wonder if the index moves during the deformation. That might help.

Comment: @ThomasRichard  What is  that deformation?. Moreover do you deform an  arbitrary  metric  a to a  metric with  constant  $g_{ij}$?

Comment: What kind of index are you thinking of? The operator described by @ThomasRichard  has selfadjoint principal symbol, so the classical definition (dim ker - dim coker) does not give anything interesting.

Comment: @SebastianGoette  I  think of  fredholm index as you mentioned. So according to your  comment  and  comment of Thomas Richard I conclude that the index is  zero. But what other type of index on can associate to differential operators?

Comment: In some cases, there are exotic indices, e.g. the parity of dim ker could be an invariant. Please check the book by Lawson-Michelsohn for details.

Comment: @SebastianGoette  thanks  for  this  reference. I  read your  comment just now.